# Animation: Copy and Paste Pose Flipped effects the originally copied pose

Tags: animation, pose-mode, timeline

I'm currently trying to animate the Rain model (v2) and am having some trouble with it. I have tried copying and flip pasting one of my poses however doing so effects the originally copied pose. And when trying to animate that original pose back to its normal shape, it affects both the pasted keyframe and another keyframe in between. Any ideas on why this might be?

Also sorry for the big post with the pictures, just wanted to make sure I gave as much information as possible.

Model: https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da

1. Original pose
2. Trying to copy the original pose
3. Paste of the pose at frame 20
4. Original pose effected by paste flipped
5. Change of the bone on the first pose [Frame 1]
6. Affects the bones of the other poses [Frame 10 and 20].

[image: Original Pose]

[image]

[image: Paste of the]

[image: Original pose effected by paste flipped]

[image: Change of the bone on the first pose]

[image: Affects the bones of the other poses.]

Comment: Hello, are you keyframing all the bones?

Comment: @moonboots I'm letting it auto-keyframe with the record button in the animation timeline

Comment: auto-keyframe won't keyframe all your bones as far as I know but only the ones you've moved, are you sure it is not your problem here?

Comment: @moonboots I've tried to keyframe the location/rotation of the bones by pressing [ I ] however it still causes the issue of effecting the bones on the first post and subsequently the other keyframe data i have

Comment: could you please describe precisely what is the problem in the picture you show? it looks like when you copy pose at frame 1 and paste flip at frame 20, the flipped pose seems goods, and back to frame 1 it seems to be like it was before, no?

Comment: @moonboots Sorry if I havent made it clear. At frame one is the original pose, but I wished to have it at frame 20 flipped. When doing so, Frame 20 comes out well but upon going back to Frame 1, the original pose is not where it used to be. As I try to move the right leg back to its original position to fix the pose, it moves the leg position of Frame 10 and Frame 20 as well when they are not selected. Auto key frame was turned on when doing this.

Comment: could you please share your file with just the pose of frame 1?

Comment: @moonboots https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4t19i09xkzmdpt/Rainv2.zip?dl=0
thanks for your help

Comment: it works fine here as long as I select everything and flip-paste so I hope someone will help  :/

Comment: @moonboots thank you anyway for your help. i've messed around with it a bit more and found that if I turn off the auto keyframer it partially stops it from interfering with other keyframes. so hopefully that continues to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. Not sure if it was the same cause, but my character was facing along the x-axis. He needed to be facing along the y-axis with the rotation applied, because the mirror paste works by x-axis mirroring.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/157285)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like the other frames weren't keyed down. Ideally you should key down every channel of your frames before copy/pasting keys, otherwise pasting keys somewhere will result in the later frames carrying the changes because of newly created keys that weren't there before, of the other way around your source frame was lacking keys which are keyed down in the target frame and result in an unexpected-looking paste.